# iPhone 5 iOS 11 Phone vibrates but does not ring when receiving calls

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 11. When I receive a call, the phone vibrates but does not ring.

1. Do Not Disturb is off
2. Mute switch is on - phone will play internet radio OK
3. When I select **Sounds > Ringtone** the phone plays the tone OK. Changing the ringtone does not make the tone play when a call is received.
4. Volume control is up

Any other suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your iPhone?

Comment: Turn the mute switch off. The behaviour you describe is exactly what happens when mute is turned on.